# What does "why why" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conversation

Excerpt from a conversation:

```
A: I have two oak trees in my backyard.
B: Why why I have two oak trees in my backyard too!
```

What is the meaning of the double "why"? It doesn't look like it's being used to ask a question, because the sentence seems to be an exclamation.

Comment: I think that you may have some missing question-marks in your sentence B. It may be: "Why? Why I have two oak trees in my backyard too?!" I have not found any online references to those sentences to include the source. Could you include it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Why" is sometimes used as an interjection or exclamation to express mild surprise, hesitation, approval, disapproval, or impatience. For example:

- Why, that useless man! (disapproval)
- Why, I was just thinking about you when you called! (surprise)

"Why" isn't the only interrogative word to be used this way, for example "*what luck!*"

In the context of your example, it would seem to be expressing surprise. However, why it is used twice in your example I have no idea. It seems wrong. Perhaps you have misquoted it, or there is some missing punctuation? If a person was especially surprised, I suppose they might stammer and say it twice?

> Why... why I have two oak trees in my backyard too!

Although I can't see what is so surprising about having the same trees.